# Slot machine like selectbox using angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, css

I am trying to build a slot machine type selector for my project, but having trouble with it. I have a popover towards right of the page by which user can open to give feedback for different sections of the page.

![example] https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2Jop.jpg

With help of up down buttons user can select the sections he wants.

Should i use
     `ng-repeat`

How can i do this?

here is the plunkr link

http://plnkr.co/edit/0a6EcJZOOM7t8lTUL4Xt?p=preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, using an `ng-repeat` would be a good choice here. As it allows to unify the element markup and easily update the number of displayed slots.

Html

```
<p ng-repeat="slot in slots" ng-class="[{'active-slot': (index === slot)}, 'slot']">
    {{items[slot].name}}
</p>
```

Controller

```
  $scope.slots = [0, 1, 2];
  $scope.index = 0;
  function recalculateSlots(){
    $scope.slots[0] = Math.min(Math.max($scope.index-1, 0), $scope.items.length-3);
    $scope.slots[1] = $scope.slots[0] + 1;
    $scope.slots[2] = $scope.slots[0] + 2;
  }
  $scope.goUp = function(){
    $scope.index = Math.max($scope.index-1, 0);
    recalculateSlots();
  };
  $scope.goDown = function(){
    $scope.index = Math.min($scope.index+1, $scope.items.length-1);
    recalculateSlots();
  };
```

Related styles

```
.slot {
  margin: 0;
}

.active-slot{
  color: blue;
}
```

[Updated plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rr0tislMoLiKNNP3FYZF)

Comment: Thanks kirill ...Can you also suggest how i should go about if i want to update the slot values based on the scroll. For example http://imgur.com/9kZNW1I the slot values are 5,6,7 based on the page view port.

Comment: It's not absolutely clear you would like to init popup selected element based on main page position or scroll page together with spinning slots in popup?

Comment: Use case is something like this 1) If user is on top of the page and if he decides to provide feedback, then he would open popover and slot values would be one,two,three

Comment: I advise you to formulate a new question, as deep comments here are unlikely to be seen by large audience

Comment: 2) Now if user decides to scroll main page further down and now the top visible section in main page is five,six and seven... now if he decides to provide feedback, then he would open popover and slot values would be five,six,seven

Comment: @saga I'd suggest a directive like [this](https://github.com/thenikso/angular-inview), but I didn't have such experience so in a new question you might get more insight